# Select the sum of values from 2 tables and group by common foreign key

Tags: mysql, sql, join

I have two tables, i want to:

[image]

**1.-select the count of each 'id_user'from table "A":**

Query:

```
SELECT COUNT(*), user.user_name as user_name
FROM A
INNER JOIN user
ON A.ID_user = user.ID_USER
GROUP BY ID_user;
```

Results:

[image]

**2.-Select the value SCORE of each 'id_user' from table "B"**

Query:

```
SELECT SCORE, user.user_name as user_name
FROM B
INNER JOIN user
ON B.id_user = user.id_user_name
GROUP BY id_user;
```

Results:

[image]

**3.-Sum those 2 values and display the total score grouped by user name:**

My expected output would be something like this including the sum of scores on table A and on table B:

Expected output:

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Is this what you want?

```
select u.*,
       (select sum(a.score) from a where a.id_user = u.id_user) as a_sum,
       (select sum(b.score) from b where b.id_user = u.id_user) as b_sum
from user u;
```

If you want the total score, just add them together:

```
select u.*,
       ( (select COUNT(1)  from a where a.id_user = u.id_user) +
         (select coalesce(sum(b.score), 0) from b where b.id_user = u.id_user)
       ) as ab_sum
from user u;
```

Comment: @ChristopherMartinez . . . If you want the total, just add them together.